# Uploading image on second mask leads to image upload on first mask

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I have 2 mask image, i am allowing user to upload image on those masks by clicking on that mask....

When I upload image on First image , than its uploading fine, but when i tried in 2nd image, still its uploading on 1st image.....

**Console** :

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided. at HTMLInputElement.fileup1.onchange

https://codepen.io/kidsdial/pen/drVmPR

Here is  [Video link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Jqt3rmFHHZQxJC-FBErnPhJiSJjRDxKp/view)

```js
var mask;

let jsonData = {
  "path" : " newyear collage\/",
  "info" : {
    "author" : "",
    "keywords" : "",
    "file" : "newyear collage",
    "date" : "sRGB",
    "title" : "",
    "description" : "Normal",
    "generator" : "Export Kit v1.2.8"
  },
  "name" : "newyear collage",
  "layers" : [
    {
      "x" : 0,
      "height" : 612,
      "layers" : [
        {
          "x" : 0,
          "color" : "0xFFFFFF",
          "height" : 612,
          "y" : 0,
          "width" : 612,
          "shapeType" : "rectangle",
          "type" : "shape",
          "name" : "bg_rectangle"
        },
        {
          "x" : 160,
          "height" : 296,
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 0,
              "height" : 296,
              "src" : "ax0HVTs.png",
              "y" : 0,
              "width" : 429,
              "type" : "image",
              "name" : "mask_image_1"
            },
            {
              "radius" : "26 \/ 27",
              "color" : "0xACACAC",
              "x" : 188,
              "y" : 122,
              "height" : 53,
              "width" : 53,
              "shapeType" : "ellipse",
              "type" : "shape",
              "name" : "useradd_ellipse1"
            }
          ],
          "y" : 291,
          "width" : 429,
          "type" : "group",
          "name" : "user_image_1"
        },
        {
          "x" : 25,
          "height" : 324,
          "layers" : [
            {
              "x" : 0,
              "height" : 324,
              "src" : "hEM2kEP.png",
              "y" : 0,
              "width" : 471,
              "type" : "image",
              "name" : "mask_image_2"
            },
            {
              "radius" : "26 \/ 27",
              "color" : "0xACACAC",
              "x" : 209,
              "y" : 136,
              "height" : 53,
              "width" : 53,
              "shapeType" : "ellipse",
              "type" : "shape",
              "name" : "useradd_ellipse_2"
            }
          ],
          "y" : 22,
          "width" : 471,
          "type" : "group",
          "name" : "user_image_2"
        }
      ],
      "y" : 0,
      "width" : 612,
      "type" : "group",
      "name" : "newyearcollage08"
    }
  ]
};

$(document).ready(function() {

$('.container').click(function(e) {
  if(e.target.getContext) {
    var pixel = e.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
    if(pixel[3] === 255) {
      setTimeout(() => {
          $('#fileup1').click();
      }, 20);
    }
  }
});

$('.container').click(function(e) {
  if(e.target.getContext) {
    var pixel = e.target.getContext('2d').getImageData(e.offsetX, e.offsetY, 1, 1).data;
    if(pixel[3] === 255) {
      setTimeout(() => {
          $('#fileup2').click();
      }, 20);
    }
  }
});



    function getAllSrc(layers) {
        let arr = [];
        layers.forEach(layer => {
            if (layer.src) {
                arr.push({
                    src: layer.src,
                    x: layer.x,
                    y: layer.y
                });
            } else if (layer.layers) {
                let newArr = getAllSrc(layer.layers);
                if (newArr.length > 0) {
                    newArr.forEach(({
                        src,
                        x,
                        y
                    }) => {
                        arr.push({
                            src,
                            x: (layer.x + x),
                            y: (layer.y + y)
                        });
                    });
                }
            }
        });
        return arr;
    }



    function json(data)

    {
        var width = 0;
        var height = 0;
        let arr = getAllSrc(data.layers);

        let layer1 = data.layers;
        width = layer1[0].width;
        height = layer1[0].height;

        for (let {
                src,
                x,
                y
            } of arr) {
            $(".container").css('width', width + "px").css('height', height + "px").addClass('temp');

            var mask = $(".container").mask({
                maskImageUrl: 'https://i.imgur.com/' + src,
                onMaskImageCreate: function(img) {

                    img.css({
                        "position": "absolute",
                        "left": x + "px",
                        "top": y + "px"
                    });
                }
            });

            fileup1.onchange = function() {
                mask.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup1.files[0]));
            };
   
   fileup2.onchange = function() {
                mask.loadImage(URL.createObjectURL(fileup2.files[0]));
            };
        }

    }
    json(jsonData);

}); // end of document ready

// jq plugin for mask
(function($) {
    var JQmasks = [];
    $.fn.mask = function(options) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            maskImageUrl: undefined,
            imageUrl: undefined,
            scale: 1,
            id: new Date().getUTCMilliseconds().toString(),
            x: 0, // image start position
            y: 0, // image start position
            onMaskImageCreate: function(div) {},
        }, options);


        var container = $(this);

        let prevX = 0,
            prevY = 0,
            draggable = false,
            img,
            canvas,
            context,
            image,
            timeout,
            initImage = false,
            startX = settings.x,
            startY = settings.y,
            div;

        container.mousePosition = function(event) {
            return {
                x: event.pageX || event.offsetX,
                y: event.pageY || event.offsetY
            };
        }

        container.selected = function(ev) {
            var pos = container.mousePosition(ev);
            var item = $(".masked-img canvas").filter(function() {
                var offset = $(this).offset()
                var x = pos.x - offset.left;
                var y = pos.y - offset.top;
                var d = this.getContext('2d').getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data;
                return d[0] > 0
            });

            JQmasks.forEach(function(el) {
                var id = item.length > 0 ? $(item).attr("id") : "";
                if (el.id == id)
                    el.item.enable();
                else el.item.disable();
            });
        };

        container.enable = function() {
            draggable = true;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "true");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 2
            });
        }

        container.disable = function() {
            draggable = false;
            $(canvas).attr("active", "false");
            div.css({
                "z-index": 1
            });
        }

        container.onDragStart = function(evt) {
            container.selected(evt);
            prevX = evt.clientX;
            prevY = evt.clientY;
            var img = new Image();
            evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 10, 10);
            evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', 'anything');
        };

        container.getImagePosition = function() {
            return {
                x: settings.x,
                y: settings.y,
                scale: settings.scale
            };
        };

        container.onDragOver = function(evt) {
            if (draggable && $(canvas).attr("active") === "true") {
                var x = settings.x + evt.clientX - prevX;
                var y = settings.y + evt.clientY - prevY;
                if (x == settings.x && y == settings.y)
                    return; // position has not changed
                settings.x += evt.clientX - prevX;
                settings.y += evt.clientY - prevY;
                prevX = evt.clientX;
                prevY = evt.clientY;
                container.updateStyle();
            }
        };

        container.updateStyle = function() {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
                context.beginPath();
                context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
                image = new Image();
                image.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                image.src = settings.maskImageUrl;
                image.onload = function() {
                    canvas.width = image.width;
                    canvas.height = image.height;
                    context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
                    div.css({
                        "width": image.width,
                        "height": image.height
                    });
                };

                img = new Image();
                img.src = settings.imageUrl;
                img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
                img.onload = function() {
                    settings.x = settings.x == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.width - (img.width * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.x;
                    settings.y = settings.y == 0 && initImage ? (canvas.height - (img.height * settings.scale)) / 2 : settings.y;
                    context.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-atop';
                    context.drawImage(img, settings.x, settings.y, img.width * settings.scale, img.height * settings.scale);
                    initImage = false;
                };
            }, 0);
        };

        // change the draggable image
        container.loadImage = function(imageUrl) {
            if (img)
                img.remove();
            // reset the code.
            settings.y = startY;
            settings.x = startX;
            prevX = prevY = 0;
            settings.imageUrl = imageUrl;
            initImage = true;
            container.updateStyle();
        };

        // change the masked Image
        container.loadMaskImage = function(imageUrl, from) {
            if (div)
                div.remove();
            canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
            canvas.setAttribute("id", settings.id);
            settings.maskImageUrl = imageUrl;
            div = $("<div/>", {
                "class": "masked-img"
            }).append(canvas);

            // div.find("canvas").on('touchstart mousedown', function(event)
            div.find("canvas").on('dragstart', function(event) {

                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.onDragStart(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").on('touchend mouseup', function(event) {
                if (event.handled === false) return;
                event.handled = true;
                container.selected(event);
            });

            div.find("canvas").bind("dragover", container.onDragOver);
            container.append(div);
            if (settings.onMaskImageCreate)
                settings.onMaskImageCreate(div);
            container.loadImage(settings.imageUrl);
        };
        container.loadMaskImage(settings.maskImageUrl);
        JQmasks.push({
            item: container,
            id: settings.id
        })
        return container;
    };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.temp {
background: black;
}

.container {
 background: black;
  position: relative;
 
}

.masked-img {
 overflow: hidden;
 margin-top: 30px;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<input id="fileup1" name="fileup1" type="file" style="display:none" >

<input id="fileup2" name="fileup2" type="file" style="display:none" >

<div class="container">

</div>
```

Comment: Your `container` click functions seem to be the problem. the container covers both `input` elements so by clicking anywhere you open both inputs at the same time. so the problem probably isnt that your second input uploads to second image but that you upload on 1st input all the time

Comment: @Matt.S Thanks a lot for suggestion, can you please tell me what changes i need to  do to make it work ?